# intellij 9 auto scroll to source

Tags: intellij-idea

Has anyone noticed that intellij 9 broke the auto scroll to source feature? it doesnt work 50% of the time.

Does anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't reproduce, works perfectly fine.

Try to run IDEA with no plug-ins and with all the default settings (rename the profile folder for this).

Also try [9.0.3 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/Maia+EAP).